# Any way to provide a separate vimrc file just for 1 session

Tags: vim, vimrc

I would like to know, if there is a way in vim/vi to provide a different vimrc file. I am looking at managing 2 different vimrc files. For the contents I checkout/checkin in version control I want to use different set of commands and not the normal one in my `.vimrc` file

For Example.

My `.vimrc` file contains a command to automatically delete any trailing space while saving a file. But, I don't want this feature to be activated for specific files.

So any way to provide a different vimrc file ( maybe at command line, giving it as parameter each time as vim --vimrc=somefile file-to-open) ?

Comment: Read `man vim` and look for `-u` and `-U`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See the manpage:

> -u {vimrc}  Use  the  commands  in the file {vimrc} for initializations.  All the other
>               initializations are skipped.  Use this to edit a special kind of files. It
>               can also be used to skip all initializations by giving the name "NONE".  See
>               ":help initialization" within vim for more details.

Comment: I created an alias on my server for loading a certain vimrc file, leaving the normal one clean for other people using it. I called it `jim`.

Answer (score 13):

> So any way to provide a different vimrc file ( maybe at command line, giving it as parameter each time as vim --vimrc=somefile file-to-open) ?

Yes, use the `-u` parameter:

```
vim -u ~/.my-custom-vimrc
```

From `man vim`:

```
   -u {vimrc}  Use  the  commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations.
               All the other initializations are  skipped.   Use  this  to
               edit  a special kind of files.  It can also be used to skip
               all initializations by giving the name "NONE".  See  ":help
               initialization" within vim for more details.
```

> My .vimrc file contains a command to automatically delete any trailing space while saving a file. But, I don't want this feature to be activated for specific files.

There's a different solution if you need special handling for some known filetypes; use the `autocmd` command in your vimrc. For example, this is my filetype-dependent configuration:

```
" Mapping of filetypes to options
au FileType freerad      setl noexpandtab sts=0 sw=8
au FileType make         setl noexpandtab sts=0
au FileType php          let php_sql_query=1
au FileType php          let php_htmlInStrings=1
au FileType python       setl shiftwidth=2 expandtab
au FileType sql          setl noexpandtab sts=0 sw=8
" global options I do not want any filetype to override
au FileType *            setl formatoptions-=ro " don't continue comments
```

If you need to apply options to something that vim doesn't automatically assign a certain filetype, you can add your own mapping (do that before using the `autocmd` command):

```
" mapping of filenames to filetypes
au FileReadPost,BufReadPost,BufNewFile /etc/freeradius/* setl ft=freerad
au FileReadPost,BufReadPost,BufNewFile *.xt              setl ft=xt
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. But i have files with same extension for which I need to have different formatting, hence need a way to give vimrc file. And got it it's the `-u` option that is needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can also `set exrc` in your main .vimrc to make vim load a .vimrc from the current directory automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If you store your Vim config directory under Git (I hope so) - you can use different branches, and checkout between them.